# Max/Min of three or more Integers if null values are allowed

Tags: java, java-8

I am wondering if there a better, short and elegant way to achieve this than what i am trying. Let's say i have 3 Integers(value1, value2, value3) and i want to find max value out of those Integers and null values are allowed for them. I cannot use below code because it could throw NullPointerException:

```
Math.max(Math.max(value1, value2), value3)
```

I have written a barbaric code(shown below) but it won't scale for more than 3 integers:

```
public Integer getMaxValue(Integer value1, Integer value2, Integer value3) {

    Integer defaultValue = 1;

    if (value1 == null && value2 == null && value3 == null) {
        return defaultValue;
    } else if (value1 == null && value2 != null && value3 != null) {
        return Math.max(value2, value3);
    } else if (value2 == null && value1 != null && value3 != null) {
        return Math.max(value1, value3);
    } else if (value3 == null && value1 != null && value2 != null) {
        return Math.max(value1, value2);
    } else if (value1 == null && value2 == null) {
        return value3;
    } else if (value2 == null && value3 == null) {
        return value1;
    } else if (value1 == null && value3 == null) {
        return value2;
    } else {
        return Math.max(Math.max(value1, value2), value3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really want a default value? IMHO null would be a reasonable choice if all values are null. Or return an Optional. Thoughts?

Comment: @Bohemian yes, unfortunately the default value is needed for what i am trying to do

Comment: You could pass the default value into the method as the first parameter. That would make for a cleaner implementation and make its behaviour more obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
public Integer getMaxValue(Integer... numbers) {
    return Arrays.stream(numbers)
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .max(naturalOrder())
      .orElse(1);
}
```

This handles any number of Integers, any or all of which can be null.

---

You could convert this to a generic method that returns [`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) rather than `T` since there is no common default value for `T`.

```
public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Optional<T> getMaxValue(T... numbers) {
    return Arrays.stream(numbers)
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .max(naturalOrder());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using Java Streams. They provide a very clean neat way to filter out nulls and return a max value, or default if all of the inputted numbers were null.

```
public Integer getMaxValue( Integer value1, Integer value2, Integer value3 ) {
    Integer defaultValue = 1;

    return Stream.of( value1, value2, value3 ) // create a stream of the values
            .filter( Objects::nonNull ) // filter out the non-null values
            .max( Comparator.naturalOrder() ) // grab the max value
            .orElse( defaultValue ); // if all of the values were null, return the default
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some good Answers already. Here is a variation if you want *both* min and max, and you have a small set of data residing in memory.

## For min *and* max

Define a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) to hold the result.

```
record MinMax( Integer min , Integer max ) { }
```

Some example data.

```
List < Integer > integers = List.of( 7 , 99 , 42 , 3 );
```

Make a [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html) from that list, after (a) skipping nulls, and (b) sorting.

```java
Deque < Integer > deque =
        integers
                .stream()
                .filter( Objects :: nonNull )
                .sorted()
                .collect( Collectors.toCollection( ArrayDeque :: new ) );
```

Pull the first (min) and last (max) from the deque. Construct a `MinMax` record.

```java
MinMax minMax = new MinMax( deque.peekFirst() , deque.peekLast() );
```

When run:

> minMax.toString() = MinMax[min=3, max=99]

If the input list contains no integers, both fields of `MinMax` are null.

If the input list contains 1 integer, both fields of `MinMax` contain the same number.

You might want to add a convenience method to your record named something like `minEqualsMax` to see [if both fields have the same number or both are null](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)).

```java
record MinMax( Integer min , Integer max ) 
{ 
    boolean minEqualsMax () { return Objects.equals( min , max ) ; }
}
```

We can move our deque code into a static factory method on the record `MinMax`. We could name this method `fromList`, but actually, this code works on any [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html). So we name it `fromCollection`.

Full class example.

```java
package work.basil.example.minmax;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public record MinMax( Integer min , Integer max )
{
    static MinMax fromCollection ( final Collection < Integer > integers )
    {
        Deque < Integer > deque =
                integers
                        .stream()
                        .filter( Objects :: nonNull )
                        .sorted()
                        .collect( Collectors.toCollection( ArrayDeque :: new ) );
        return new MinMax( deque.peekFirst() , deque.peekLast() );
    }

    boolean minEqualsMax ( ) { return Objects.equals( min , max ); }
}
```

Now we can write simple code like:

```
MinMax minMax = MinMax.fromCollection( List.of( 7 , 99 , 42 , 3 ) ) ;
```

Demo code.

```java
List < List < Integer > > lists =
        List.of(
                List.of( 7 , 99 , 42 , 3 ) ,
                List.of( 42 ) ,
                List.of()
        );
lists.forEach(
        list -> System.out.println( MinMax.fromCollection( list ) )
);
```

When run:

```
MinMax[min=3, max=99]
MinMax[min=42, max=42]
MinMax[min=null, max=null]
```

Caveat: Sorting is expensive if you have a very large number of elements, or if the elements are not all loaded into memory. For those cases, do not use the approach of this Answer. But for common cases such as processing line items on an invoice, this approach is reasonable.

Comment: One inefficiency with this implementation is that the entire stream needs to be copied into an in-memory collection, which depending on the source of the stream, could potentially be incredibly large.  This could be easily fixed by using `.reduce` with an operator that merged two `MinMax` values together, instead of `.collect`.

Comment: @M.Justin Valid point. I added a disclaimer up top and at bottom. Thank you.

Comment: Hm ... why not simply use `Collectors.summarizingInt`? That gives both min and max,  is easier to write, and faster to execute ...

Comment: Or `Collectors.teeing(Collectors.minBy(order), Collectors.maxBy(order), MinMax::new)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner solution that uses [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```java
Stream.of(value1, value2, value3)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .reduce(Math::max)
        .orElse(defaultValue);
```

This creates a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) containing the three values, filters out the nulls, calls `Math.max` on the elements pairwise, returning the given value or `defaultValue` if all values were null.

Comment: I'm leaving this up as an example for how to do it for binary functions in general, but I somehow gapped that I could just use the `.max` method on `Stream`.  I would recommend that approach over this one for this specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use preconditional checks:

```
public Integer getMaxValue(Integer one, Integer two, Integer thr) {
    //Assign nulls min values, or keep if non-null
    one = one == null ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : one;
    two = two == null ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : two;
    thr = thr == null ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : thr;
    //perform comparison on non-null values
    return Math.max(Math.max(one, two), three);
}
```

By using `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, you ensure any other `Integer` will be greater than (or equal to) the result of the `null` inputs.

It should be noted that `getMaxValue(null, null, null)` in this case would result in a `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. If you want that case handled, then you could do a precheck for all three being null, and return something else accordingly.

(Note the streams solutions works well for N inputs, but in this specific case may be overkill).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach by sorting nulls first: Add your values into a list, sort them in natural order and nulls first, check if last element after sorting is null, if yes return default value else return the last value:

```
public Integer getMaxValue(Integer... numbers) {

    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(numbers);
    list.sort(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()));

    return list.get(list.size() - 1) == null ? 1 : list.get(list.size() - 1);
}
```